# Congruence problem $12x\equiv3\pmod{45}$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, congruences

$$12x\equiv3\pmod{45}$$
Find all possible solutions to above congruence and show procedure in detail.

Comment: First step: The congruence is equivalent to $4x\equiv 1\pmod{15}$.

Comment: Found and shown, now what?

Comment: Then $4x \equiv 16 (mod 15)$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! What work have you done on this problem so far, and where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have done significant work on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing through by $3$ we get , $$4x \equiv 1 \pmod {15} \Rightarrow 4\cdot4x \equiv 4\cdot1 \pmod{15}$$

$$\Rightarrow x\equiv4\pmod{15}$$

$$\Rightarrow x = 15k+4 \text{ where } k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

As $(12,3,45)=3$

divide throughout by $3$ to find $$4x\equiv1\pmod{15}\equiv16$$

$$4x\equiv16\pmod{15}\iff x\equiv4\pmod{\dfrac{15}{(15,4)}}$$